Parameters to characterize heat dispersion
I'm working in a team to model some production machinery in a factory. They ask me to find a way to describe and quantify the heat loss to be able to make an initial and approximate comparison between the machines and possibly, if there was a machine that heats the environment considerably, to quantify how much to lower the heating in the area. I don't need to be 100% accurate but I don't want to oversimplify.
I have no information from the machine manufacturer but we can use a thermographic camera to better understand where and how the dispersion occurs.
The proposal that emerged was to use an average between the temperature peaks and divide it by the surface, creating a parameter similar to thermal transmittance. How much sense does it make?
Are there other methods that might be better but equally not overly complicated?

Just assume that 100% of the energy (electricity, fuel or whatever) sent into the machine gets turned into heat, one way or another. Any heat not carried away by the output products stays in the factory.

@DaveTweed I'm not clear on your comment... are you implying that I'm oversimplifying it? your proposal makes no sense anyway, some of the energy is spent on the process and cannot be neglected

@M4rc0txt, no you are over-complicating it.  Unless the process is consuming heat (like by making steam), all the electricity will turn into heat.

@TigerGuy
I am not convinced. if this were the case then all industries would only need powerful air conditioners. all machines use a part of energy, perhaps a small one, to do work of some kind. It seems to me that simplifying the whole process turns all the energy into heat is oversimplifying

Most industries DO use powerful air conditioners. Try to work out for a particular process what part of the energy input does not get turned into heat. For example, suppose you have a big press that shapes sheet metal for car bodies. Some of the electricity gets turned directly into heat in the motor. Some gets turned into heat as friction in the transmission system and the mechanism of the press. The shaping of the sheet metal generates heat within the metal itself and in the dies. All of this heat ends up in the factory air.

Agree with @DaveTweed and TigerGuy.  The amount of total energy transformed into mechanical energy will be small compared to the amount of energy transformed into heat (for most cases).

Looks to me that the question is regarding how to lower heating of the ambient supposedly for human habitation to take advantage of a high heat output device in the production area, i.e.,  "if there was a machine that heats the environment considerably, to quantify how much to lower the heating in the area ".  Question is not how to cool the entire production area.
